# Laravel Installation shows blank page. Error:unexpected T_STRING

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to upload my laravel project in host. But when i hit the url, it gives an blank page. When i checked in the error log, it is showing following errors:

```
[23-Jan-2018 23:01:35] PHP Warning:  Unexpected character in input:  '\' (ASCII=92) state=1 in /home4/knownepa/public_html/tra/index.php on line 51
[23-Jan-2018 23:01:35] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home4/knownepa/public_html/tra/index.php on line 51
```

I have following lines of code in those lines:

```
$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: show us this file `/home4/knownepa/public_html/tra/index.php`

Comment: @Sohel0415 i have included the codes.

Comment: Please check if there is a .env file in your root-project-folder. If not, rename the ```example.env``` to ```.env```

Comment: What version of PHP is running on your server? Also, which line is #51?

Comment: What PHP version are you use?

Comment: @Anon add your view file

Comment: @Phil PHP version is:5.6.32

Comment: @Sohel0415 I have added full file link

Comment: what's your laravel version??

Comment: @Sohel0415 Its 5.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with your PHP version.

Your `PHP` version should be above 5.2, as PHP 5.2 and below don't support namespaces.

**In fact, Laravel 5.5  requires PHP 7.0 and above.**

Laravel [requirements](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/installation#installation)

**But as your Laravel Version is 5.2, from the Laravel 5.2 [docs](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.2)**

Your PHP version should be atleast 5.5.9 or above.

So I suggest you to update to the latest version of PHP to avoid these type of issues.

Comment: PHP version is 5.6.32

Comment: @Anon laravel 5.5 requires PHP 7.0 and above please update your PHP version

Comment: Laravel version is 5.2

Comment: I have tried to upload project in host with php>7. It shows following error log:
[24-Jan-2018 06:23:11 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function Symfony\Polyfill\Mbstring\iconv_strpos() in /home/mayurstay/public_html/vendor/symfony/polyfill-mbstring/Mbstring.php:363

Comment: [24-Jan-2018 06:23:11 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function Symfony\Polyfill\Mbstring\iconv_strpos() in /home/mayurstay/public_html/vendor/symfony/polyfill-mbstring/Mbstring.php:363

Comment: @Anon try `composer require symfony/polyfill-iconv` and then `composer dumpautoload`

Comment: How can i install it in cPanel?

Comment: @Anon you need to ssh into your server and first install composer and then pull in the dependency.

Comment: @Anon please accept my answer and upvote it if helped you.

Comment: Is there any other way to do this? SSH seems to be disabled in my host.

Comment: @Anon the only other way is to set up the project in your dev machine install composer and dependency there and then push the entire project to host.

Comment: It gave following warning:
Warning: Ambiguous class resolution, "SebastianBergmann\GlobalState\Exception" was found in both "I:\Longtail\TRA\tra-shared\vendor/sebastian/global-state/src/Exception.php" and "I:\Longtail\TRA\tra-shared\vendor/sebastian/global-state/src/exceptions\Exception.php", the first will be used.

Comment: @Anon All of these problems are due to your older Laravel version. Please try to update your project to use the latest version